# uri path is invalid

Tags: android, html, ios, flutter

I'm working on a flutter app and part of the configuration asks for the url, I've installed the web admin interface on a subdomain.

```
static const String api_url = "app.sitename.co.uk/api/";
```

I issue the command flutter run which throws this:-

The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec:
Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI

If I move the web admin to sitename.co.uk/app/api I then get the following error:-

[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid character (at character 16) asitename.co.uk/app/api  which is the forward slash

I don't want to run the web admin interface inside my root directory, I would rather run it on the subdomain or inside another folder under my root. Does anybody know why the app would throw these errors and how I resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: can you elaborate more?  you have to parse the Url with `Uri.parse('your url')`

Comment: Your URL is missing a scheme.  For example, it probably should be `'https://api.sitename.co.uk/api/'`.

Comment: Hi, I've tried with 'https://api.sitename.co.uk/api/' and I still get:

The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec:
Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI

For completeness, this is the dart code I need to update

class apiConfig {
  static const String api_url = "https://app.sitenam.co.uk/api/";
  static const String api_token = "8315ece27cbfcd47c35773402094c960";
  static const String item_purchase_code =
      "9a73490a-xxx-xxx-xxx-cbb3e7a612f4";
}

Answer (score 1):

Using URL's typically you'd want to initialise it with the URI class, rather than String;

```
void main() {
 
  String _url = 'app.sitename.co.uk';
  
  Uri url = Uri(host: _url, scheme: "https", path: 'api');
  
  print(url);
}
```

[DartPad example](https://dartpad.dev/?https%3A%2F%2Fgist.github.com%2Fleccles1%2Fbacdf4a41da799aa937d41450d671269)

Output:

```
https://app.sitename.co.uk/api
```

Depending on how you're using the String URL (if a library is used) It might be that the specific library doesn't handle URL parsing from just a String and requires it as a URI object.